# Problema de Posicionamiento y Clonando objetos en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

**En la función copiarContenido del código estoy clonando con JavaScript la entrada del select en una ListaA, el conflicto que estoy tenido es que se clone debajo de la primer entrada (DENTRO DE OTRO SELECT) para poder mover  la primera entrada a la ListaB ,y la copia o clonación permanezca en la ListaA, el resultado de la copia la estoy visualizando en un span, en el cual quiero q este situada dentro del select la cual es la ListaA**

````js
```Funcion de copia en Js```

    function copiarContenido(){
    let copi = document.getElementById('ListaA');
    let cop = copi.value;
    document.getElementById('Seleccionado').innerText = `${cop}.`;
}
    function addItem(){
        var myText = document.getElementById('Text1');
        if (myText.value ==''|| myText.value ==""){
            alert('Debes agregar');
            return;
        }

        if(document.getElementById('Radio1').checked){
            var oSelFied = document.getElementById('ListaA');
            var oOption = document.createElement("option");
            oSelFied.add(oOption);
            oOption.text = myText.value;
            oOption.value = myText.value;
        }else{
            var oSelFied = document.getElementById('ListaB');
            var oOption = document.createElement("option");
            oSelFied.add(oOption);
            oOption.text = myText.value;
            oOption.value = myText.value;
        }
        myText.value ="";
        ListaA.concat(ListaB);
        PersistState();
        return;
    }
    function moveToRight(){
        var e = document.getElementById("ListaA");
        var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
        var oSelFied = document.getElementById("ListaB");
        var oOption = document.createElement("option");
        oSelFied.add(oOption);
        oOption.text = strUser;
        oOption.value = strUser;

        e.options.remove(e.selectedIndex);
        PersistState();
    }
    function removeA(){
        var e = document.getElementById("ListaA");
        if (e.selectedIndex >=0) {
        e.options.remove(e.selectedIndex);
      }
        var i = document.getElementById("ListaB");
        if (i.selectedIndex >=0) {
        i.options.remove(i.selectedIndex);
        PersistState();
        }
    
  }
    function PersistState(){
        var e = document.getElementById("ListaA");
        var f = document.getElementById("ListaB");
        var theString = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < e.options.lenght; i++){
        if (i !=(e.options.lenght-1)){
            theString +=e.options[1].text +",";
        }else{
            theString +=e.options[1].text;
        }
    }
    var theString2 = "";
    for(var i = 0; i < e.options.lenght; i++){
        if (i !=(e.options.lenght-1)){
            theString2 +=e.options[1].text +",";
        }else{
            theString2 +=e.options[1].text;
        }
    }
    sessionStorage.myListaA= theString;
    sessionStorage.myListaB = theString2;
    }

    function loadState(){
        if (sessionStorage.myListaA){
            var theString = sessionStorage.myListaA;
            var hey = theString.split(",");
            for (var i = 0; i < hey.lenght; i++){
            var oSelFied = document.getElementById("ListaA");
            var oOption = document.createElement("option");
            oSelFied.add(oOption);
            oOption.Text = hey[i];
            oOption.value = hey [i];
            };
        }
        if (sessionStorage.myListaB){
            var theString = sessionStorage.myListaB;
            var hey = theString.split(",");
            for (var i = 0; i < hey.lenght; i++){
                var oSelFied = document.getElementById("ListaB");
                var oOption = document.createElement("option");
                oSelFied.add(oOption);
                oOption.Text = hey[i];
                oOption.value = hey [i];
            }
        }
    }
````

```css
#caja{
            background-color: gray;
            border: outset #777;
            height: 441px;
            width: 380px;
            margin: auto;
            padding: 15px;
            margin-top: 0px;
        }
        .la{
            float: left;
        }
        .lb{
            float: right;
        }
        #btns{
            margin-top: 30px;
            margin-left: 150px;
        }
        input{
            margin-right: 10px;
            margin-left: 15px;
        }
        select{
            margin-left: 6px;
            width: 128px;
            margin-top: 20px;
        }

         .copia{
     background-color:#E4C220;
     width:100%;
     padding:25px; }
*Estos son los estilos para visualizar la posición de la copia *
```

```html
<body  onload="loadState();">
            <div id="caja">
                <h7 class="profile-title"><strong style="font-size: 14px;"><center>Selecion Orden de Producción</center></strong></h7>
                <center><select style="width: 50px;" id="Text1"name="Tipo_de_arreglo" required>
                  <option value="A1">A1</option>
                  <option value="A2">A2</option>
                  <option value="A3">A3</option>
                  <option value="A4">A4</option>
                </select></center>
                Pendientes: <input id="Radio1" type="radio" name="Lista" value="ListaA" checked="checked"><br>
                Impresion: <input id="Radio2" type="radio" name="Lista" value="ListaB"/><br>

                <input type="button" id="btnAgregar" value="Agregar" onclick="addItem();"/>
                <input class="la" type="button" value="Eliminar" id="btnEliminarA" onclick="removeA();">
                <input type="button" value=">>" id="btntoRigth" name="btnToRigth" onclick="moveToRight();">
                <input type="button" value="Copiar" id="copiarContenido" onclick="copiarContenido();">
                
                <select tabindex="0" class="la" name="ListaA" id="ListaA" size="10"></select>
                <select tabindex="0" class="lb" name="ListaB" id="ListaB" size="10"></select>
                <span class="copia" id="Seleccionado"></span>
            </div>
    
</body>

*Dentro del select ListaA es en donde requiero que se cree la copia o clonacion de la primera entrada*
```

Comment: Puedes usar la función  de **jQuery** ``$(...).clone()``, no?

Comment: Hola Marcos si efectivamente utilice JQuery gracias, tengo otra pregunta en mi block crees que me puedas ayudar